# Getting heap corruption when writing to a file

Tags: c++, ifstream, heap-corruption, powerset

Im trying to write a powerset to a file, but I get a heap corruption if my starting array is bigger than size 6, and im not sure why.  It works fine with any size of array 6 or under.  Cant figure this out.

Also,  test.txt is where I read in the array.  If the file contains"1,2,3,4,5,6" it works fine, but it it contains "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" I get heap corruption.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include "N26.h"
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

void increaseArray(int* theArray, int size)  
{  
    int i = size;  
    int n = i+1;  
    int* newArray = new int[n];  

    for(int cnt=0;cnt<n;cnt++)
    {  
        newArray[cnt] = theArray[cnt];  
    }  

    newArray[n-1]= NULL;
    theArray = newArray;

    return;  
} 

void printPowerSet(int *s, int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    ofstream myFile;
    double SetSize=pow(2.0,n);

    myFile.open("powerset1.txt", std::ios_base::app);

    cout<<"{size of  original}"<< n <<endl;
    cout<<"{number of sets}"<< SetSize-1 <<endl;

    for(i=1;i<SetSize;++i)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;++j)
        {
            if(((i>>j)&1)==1)
            {           
                myFile << s[j] <<",";
            }
        }

        myFile<<endl;
    }

    return;
}

int main()
{
   ifstream myFile;
   int item;
   string input ="";

   string fileName = "test.txt";

    myFile.open(fileName);
    while(myFile)
    {   
        int k = 1;
        int* transaction= new int[1];

        if(!getline(myFile,input))
            break;

        istringstream ss(input);
        while(ss)
        {
            if(!getline(ss,input, ','))
                break;

            input.erase(remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), isspace), input.end());
            item = atoi(input.c_str());
            transaction[k-1] = item;
            increaseArray(transaction,k);

            k++;
        }

        for(int i =0; i<k-1;i++)
        {
            cout << transaction[i];
        }
        printPowerSet(transaction, k-1);
            cout << endl;
        transaction=NULL;
}

    system("Pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `increaseArray()` function doesn't work because you're only changing a local copy of the pointer. You'd have to pass a double pointer or a pointer reference to do what you want.

Example of a reference to pointer:
    void increaseArray(int*& theArray, int size)

Instead, I'd recommend using a `std::vector`, since this will grow automatically.

I doubt this has any bearing on your problem, but I don't see that you ever delete, either. You are leaking memory. Before reassigning your pointer with a new allocation, delete the old allocation:

```
delete [] theArray; // The "[]" is important!
theArray = newArray;
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill work on my increaseArray() function.  Im not allowed to use STL :(

Comment: Ah, thanks I think it worked!

When I call increaseArray, I used increaseArray(*&transaction,k)
And now the parameters are void increaseArray(int*& theArray, int size) 

That is what you meant correct?

Comment: Yes, but see my edit about memory leaks, and Nikolai's answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Fred's answer.

Look at what's going on inside `increaseArray()`, specifically these lines:

```
int i = size;  
int n = i+1;  
int* newArray = new int[n];  

for(int cnt=0;cnt<n;cnt++)
{  
    newArray[cnt] = theArray[cnt];  
}
```

You allocate an array of `size + 1` elements, and then iterate over the original. That's off-by-one, i.e. you are accessing one element outside of the original array. That *might* get you a segmentation fault depending on how `new` lays out the heap, but sure is [**undefined behavior**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).